# Convert two fields (Month and Year) into a YYYY-MM-DD Field

Tags: hana, alteryx

I am using SAP HANA SQL (Through Alteryx) via an in-DB formula.

I have two fields (Month and YEAR) and I need to convert/combine these into one field shown as YYYY-MM-DD. I am able to do this succesfully locally in Alteryx but I need to make this happen within the DB via SQL.

See image for succesful local conversion in Alteryx:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two goals here:

1. construct a **valid** date from `year` and `month` information.
2. represent this date in a specific format, ie. `YYYY-MM-DD`

The first part can be done in HANA like this:

```
to_date( "<year_column>" || "<month_column>", 'YYYYMM') as newDate
```

The double-pipe `||` operator concatenates *strings*, which means, that `<year_column>` and `<month_column>` data will be first converted into strings if these are not already string-values.

The concatenated string is then turned into a **date** data type. The `to_date` conversion function takes the pattern string `YYYYMM` and since the **day** information is missing, it makes it up on the fly and sets the day to the first day of the month.
This `to_date` conversion also checks for that only *valid* dates are created.
If, for example, the `MM` would not be a value between `01` and `12` then the conversion would fail with an error.

This brings me to the next potential obstacle to look out for: the conversion string pattern `YYYYMM` requires that there will be exactly four digits denoting the year and exactly two digits for the month.
While this may be fine for the existing *year* data as most dates are denoted with four digits nowadays, there is a good chance that the *month* data does not have a **leading zero** (e.g. when the data is currently stored in a numeric field).

To "fix" this issue, we can just add the leading zero for all values that only have a single digit so far. There's a couple of ways to do this in HANA, and as this does not seem to be in an ABAP context, I'd go with a way that works on most SQL databases:
`LPAD ("<month_column>", 2, '0')`

This gets us to the following expression for step 1:

```
to_date( "<year_column>" || LPAD ("<month_column>", 2, '0'), 'YYYYMM') as newDate
```

Step 2 now is relatively easy: turn the *date*-data that we constructed in step 1 and represent it in a specific format.
Since *date*-data per se does not have a specific output format (ie. you can display or print the same date format any way you like - it doesn't change the data), it needs to be converted to a *string* for that.

The conversion function for that is called `TO_NVARCHAR()` and can also take a conversion pattern:

`to_nvarchar( "<date_data>", 'YYYY-MM-DD') as fixedFormatDate`

is what we're looking for this question.

Putting it all together into a single expression:

```
to_nvarchar(to_date( "<year_column>" 
                     || LPAD ("<month_column>", 2, '0')
                    , 'YYYYMM')
           , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as fixedFormatDate
```

While this is a long answer to a seemingly simple question, I believe it is important to understand all the involved steps that are necessary for this conversion.

Comment: I follow the logic, but perhaps Ive done something wrong. See paste below:                                                                            

Script: to_nvarchar(to_date( "Year Combined" || LPAD ( "Month Combined",2,'0')  , 'YYYYMM')
, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as fixedFormatDate

Error: 
Formula In-DB (51): Error SQLPrepare: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "as": line 4 col 17 (at pos 691)

Comment: That means your data - after the concatenation of the two fields - does not match the `YYYYMM` pattern. Check those input columns to see where the deviation comes from.